# IndexError - Showing as out of range even though I letter for letter copied someone else's code

Tags: python, csv, index-error

I'm trying to search through a csv file however I keep getting the error message
IndexError: list index out of range.

Here is my code, please help i'm at my wits end.
To create the list out of the csv file:

```
existing_clients = []
with open("mock_data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        existing_clients.append(row)
```

And where i'm encountering the error:

```
first_name = input("Please enter the client's first name, note that the search function is case sensitive:")
name = [x[0] for x in existing_clients]
print(name)
```

Help me please I'm incredibly beginner and lost.

Comment: @DWKOT If the file did not exist, the `open()` call would have thrown an error.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `mock_data.csv` file?

Comment: Besides the obvious fact that you need to show us the contents of `mock_data.csv`, another very basic debugging step you should've done would be to print out `existing_clients` before you iterate through it. It seems like at least one row's length is zero, since `x[0]` on an item `x`, even if that `x` is a list with length 0, will cause that error. You do have data in `mock_data.csv`, right? There's no blank lines in the file? You copy-pasted your code but you never mentioned how you got the data.